# Embeding youtube videos with playlist parameter

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the javascript youtube api to embed youtube videos, i am having difficulty in embedding playlists using the swfobject.embed functionality. The code im using which i found in the javascript api docs is:

```
var splitSrc = src.split(",");

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent", allowFullScreen: "true" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

    if (splitSrc.length > 1) {
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + splitSrc[0] + "?showsearch=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&rel=0&fs=1&playlist=" + src,
                   "PlayerYoutube", "0", "0", "8", null, null, params, atts);
    }
```

where src is a comma seperated list of video ids, but the player loads just the first video specified in splitSrc[0].

Is there another way of doing this?
Am i doing this wrong?

Please could someone help me with this issue.

I have another work arround but its going to be a lot of implementation involved, i would rather have a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [embedded AS2 player has been deprecated](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#ExampleUsage) and the playlist parameter doesn't appear to work with it.

You'll need to use the embedded AS3 player, which just requires you to add `version=3` to the parameter list.

Example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/NKU6oOUho74?version=3&showsearch=0&version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&rel=0&fs=1&playlist=uDEQVgyNz88,AmKwF_Si734
```

Other tips:

- The ID of the initial video should not be in the playlist, unless you want it to play twice.
- Add a loop=1 if you don't want the player to stop when the list is finished. Without loop=1, even the user can't restart the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should add **&playnext=1** to your URL.